# Extracting fields from a url in scala-js

Tags: scala.js

Suppose I've a url like :

```
https://example.com/myproject/index-dev.html?_ijt=hsdlgh8h5g8hh489sajoej&a=102&b=a%20m&c=45&d=all&e=all
```

or it may be a webpage on localhost like :

```
localhost:63342/my project/index-dev.html?_ijt=hsdlgh8h5g8hh489sajoej&a=102&b=a%20m&c=45&d=all&e=all
```

and I've to extract query fields (appearing after '?') from these urls in 2-D array as following :

```
_ijt    |    hsdlgh8h5g8hh489sajoej
a       |    102
b       |    a m
c       |    45
d       |    all
e       |    all
```

Please do note that in 'b' field, I've replaced '%20' with a space. These fields like _ijt,a,b,c,d,e etc can vary in number and their names eg 'a' can be 'city'. 
So far I've used regular expression to extract out the part after '?' and then use split("&") method to split the string into multiple strings. 
Code -

```
val url=localhost:63342/my project/index-dev.html?_ijt=hsdlgh8h5g8hh489sajoej&a=102&b=a%20m&c=45&d=all&e=all
val pattern="""(http|htpps)([A-Za-z0-9\:\/\%\-\.]*)\?""".r
val temp_url=pattern.replaceFirstIn(url,"")
val fields=temp_url.split("&")
println(fields.foreach(println))
```

and the output is :

```
_ijt=hsdlgh8h5g8hh489sajoej
a=102
b=a%20m
c=45
d=all
e=all
```

But it doesn't seem to be the correct way to do this. Any help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `js.URIUtils.decodeURIComponent` to accurately decode the `%`-encoded characters.

Comment: It solves the issue in 'a%20m' but suppose at the end of the url, I add `#clinic` then it will show `engine=all#clinic` which is undesirable. Further I've to use `fields.foreach(println)` to print those fields. But I want to store each field into a separate variable. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Use `java.net.URI` to reliably parse a URL like that. It is supported by Scala.js (`java.net.URL` is not, though).

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `js.URIUtils.decodeURIComponent` on query parameter values:

```
val fields=temp_url.split("&").map(js.URIUtils.decodeURIComponent)
```

`decodeURIComponent` is a [native Javascript function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent), for which scala.js has [a simple interface](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/blob/8ec1b401b29277aaca6601df7c6d967a754b69cc/library/src/main/scala/scala/scalajs/js/URIUtils.scala#L28).

Alternatively, you could use some library for parsing URLs written in Scala. Parsing URLs is often a security hazard, and it's easy to make a mistake. Libraries also typically support any input that satisfies the relevant Standards / RFCs.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, it's hard to find a library for the whole thing that works both in Scala.js and Scala(jvm).  java.net.URI will get you the query string, and java.net.URLDecoder.decode will remove the URL encoding, but I haven't seen anything that gets you nicely structured query pieces.  It's not rocket science, but it's so common that you'd think you wouldn't need to write it yourself.

[Fastparse](http://www.lihaoyi.com/fastparse/) will do the job:

```
  val url = new java.net.URI("http://example.com/?a=1&b%20=b+is+2&c=#someAnchor?a=b")
  println(s"query string is: ${url.getQuery}")

  val individualElements =
    P(CharsWhile {
      case '&' | '=' | '#' => false
      case _ => true
    }.!.map(x => java.net.URLDecoder.decode(x, "UTF-8")))

  val keyValuePair: core.Parser[(String, Option[String]), Char, String] =
    individualElements ~ "=" ~ individualElements.?

  val pairs: core.Parser[Seq[(String, Option[String])], Char, String] =
    keyValuePair.rep(sep = "&")

  val parsed: Parsed[Seq[(String, Option[String])], Char, String] =
    pairs.parse(url.getQuery)

  parsed match {
    case Success(items, _) => println(s"items: ${items.toList}")
    // prints:
    // items: List((a,Some(1)), (b ,Some(b is 2)), (c,None))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the suggestions to use "decodeURIComponent" and "java.net.URI" I came up with this quick and dirty solution that almost certainly could be improved but perhaps it helps:

```
def getUrlParameters(url: String): Map[String, Array[String]] = {
    java.net.URI.create(url).getQuery.split('&').map(js.URIUtils.decodeURIComponent).map { p =>
      val split = p.split('=')
      (split.head, split.tail.mkString("="))
    }.groupBy(_._1).map(m => m._1 -> m._2.map(_._2))
}

def getUrlParameter(url: String, parameter: String): Option[String] = {
    getUrlParameters(url).get(parameter).flatMap(_.headOption)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit too late, however out of hope, to be helpful to anybody come here from google; let:

```
def uriParameterExtractor(uri: String): Map[String, String] =
js.URIUtils.decodeURIComponent(uri).tail.split("&").toList.map(x => (x.split("=").head, x.split("=").tail.head)).toMap
```

then call this function with `dom.window.location.search` argument. You can query any parameter value of interest by using respective key on result of this function, i.e:

- `uriParameterExtractor(dom.window.location.search)("a")` will evaluate to `102`
- `uriParameterExtractor(dom.window.location.search)("b")` will evaluate to `a m`
- and etc.

Answer (score -1):

Use this scala / scalajs library:
https://github.com/lemonlabsuk/scala-uri

```
import io.lemonlabs.uri.Url

val uri = Url.parse("http://example.com/path?a=b&a=c&d=e")
uri.query.paramMap // This is: Map("a" -> Vector("b", "c"), "d" -> Vector("e"))
```